# Find the Largest Contingous Sub Array using the Sliding Window Approach

Tags: arrays, algorithm, optimization, sliding-window

i am a bit confused on a sliding window problem, the problem statement is relatively simple,  given  a parameter k where k is the size of the window, find the largest sum possible.

For example

array[] = {4,2,1,7,8,1,2,7,1,0} k = 3, the largest contingous sub array is {7,8,1} which is equal to 16

I have the code, here but I do not understand one line.

```
 *public static int findMaxSumSubarray(int[] arr, int k)
{
 int currentSum = 0;
 int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
 for(int i = 0; i<arr.length;++i)
 {
     currentSum += arr[i];
    

     /*
     lets take an array example  let arr = {4,2,1,7,8,1,2,7,1,0}
     when i is at k-1 then we have effectively covered a valid subset, lets say
     k = 3, when i moves to  the third element which is 1, a valid subset has been 
     covered
      */
     
       if(i >= k - 1)
     {
          max = Math.max(max,currentSum);
          currentSum -= arr[i - (k-1)];
     }
 }
 return  max;
}**
```

The line i don't quite understand is currentSum -= arr[i-(k-1)]

Can someone please provide a small desk check/example of what is happening here it will greatly be appreciated

**My understanding**

Lets take our previous array = {4,2,1,7,8,1,2,7,1,0}

We will iterate until element at index 2, we get 4+2+1, thus we have covered a valid window size, once this is done, the compiler moves to the if statement,
since i is obviously less than or equal to k-1 we will execute this block.

currentSum -= arr[i - (k-1)];  **What is happening here?**

Apologies in advance for the formatting, and thank you to all those answer.

Comment: It's subtracting the first value of the current contiguous subarray before you add the last value of the next contiguous subarray. So when you're at `(4,2,1)` with `currentSum = 7` and about to move to `(2,1,7)`, it deletes 4 (`arr[2-(3-1)] = arr[0]`) from `currentSum` before it adds 7 (`arr[3]`)

Comment: @E-SetPrimeEpsilon any update?

Comment: Yea thank you so much it is so much more clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(i >= k - 1)
```

This check is to make sure the `sum` variable always has a sum of `k` elements.
If window size is `k`, then all good. Then size becomes `k+1` when moving to next `i`. Now, sum has value of `k+1` elements, so you remove the *first element from last window* from `sum` to make `sum` have again sum of `k` elements. See image below for more clarity for `k = 3`.

[image]

As you can see in the above picture, for every *next* window of size `k`, we have to remove previous window's first element which is done in `currentSum -= arr[i - (k-1)];`